# Why can't the forEach onClick function find methods in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick, nuxt.js

[Here's a link](https://codepen.io/sandalwoodsh/project/editor/ZoqBjd) to a working version of this on Codepen. When I port this code over to Nuxt, the onclick function can't find the method I'm calling.

Here's the problematic code block (it's found in the eachSVG.js file). Essentially what this code does is cycle through a bunch of SVGs and writes new properties to each of them; including an on click event that calls a function. :

```js
containers.forEach(function(container, index) {

    container.num = index;
    let myX = container.getBBox().x;
    let myCenterX = -1;
    let myY = container.getBBox().y;
    let myCenterY = -1;
    container.OrigXPos = myX - 200;
    container.OrigYPos = myY;
    container.description = arr_textDescription[index]

    switch (true) {
        case myY < centerPointSVG_y:
            //myCenterY = myY;
            break;
        case myY > centerPointSVG_y:
            //myCenterY = -(myY - centerPointSVG_y);
            container.OrigYPos = myY + 25;
            break;
    }
     //set up click events for each SVG icon
    container.onclick = function() {
        animateViewBox(container);
    };
});
```

Comment: What should happen if `myY == centerPointSVG_y`? That condition isn't in your `switch`.

Comment: I think it should work. If you add `console.log("clicked")` to the onclick function do you see the console messages?

Comment: What’s the error?  AnimateViewBox is undefined?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the outer code. You'll see it in the linked Codepen code though. the onclick function DOES indeed give me a console message. The error I receive in Nuxt is "this.animateViewBox is not a function" When I console log "this" it only returns the SVG group.